# Why does the mugger that Finch pays off react this way?

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

This is about the 2nd last scene in season 4 episode 6 of *Person of Interest*, where Finch is paying off the mugger.

I understand why the mugger is agitated at Finch given the umbrella takedown, but why did he then call Elizabeth Bridges a "bitch" and tell Finch to "stay away from her"? Was the mugger just blowing off more steam and lashing out, was there a plot detail I missed, or...?

Answer (score 3):

No cannon explanation is given. Here, I provide you with an out-of-universe explanation: (ending in speculation)

This exchange is a [plot coupon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotCoupon), which could bring relevance for this character, should he ever return. In the meantime, it brings depth to the scene, in that there might be more than meets the eye going on here, and that this might not be the only type of 'service' he provides Finch.

Assuming the mugger doesn't hold a general animosity towards women, he must know *something*. {insert theme song clip here} He did have numerous hours to browse her search history...

The answer is, "or..."